# Tensorflow gives unexpected keyword argument 'blacklist' error

Tags: windows, tensorflow, conda, tf-agent

This code was running well in Ubuntu using conda. Then I had to move to a windows environment where I tried to create a similar conda environment. When I try running it, the error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biplavc\Documents\AoI_work\envs\dist_AoI_ver5\main_tf.py", line 30, in <module>
    from create_graph_1 import *
  File "C:\Users\biplavc\Documents\AoI_work\envs\dist_AoI_ver5\create_graph_1.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tf_environment import *
  File "C:\Users\biplavc\Documents\AoI_work\envs\dist_AoI_ver5\tf_environment.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tf_agents.environments import py_environment
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tf_agents.environments import utils
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tf_agents.policies import random_py_policy
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\policies\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tf_agents.policies import epsilon_greedy_policy
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\policies\epsilon_greedy_policy.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tf_agents.policies import greedy_policy
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\policies\greedy_policy.py", line 42, in <module>
    @gin.configurable(module='tf_agents', blacklist=['policy'])
TypeError: configurable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blacklist'
```

I also couldn't come across any other errors similar to this and any help to sort this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please add how are you creating it?

Comment: @noober I am sorry but I didn't get your question. What did you mean by creating?

Comment: noober means you should add some code to reproduce your error.

Comment: @noober https://github.com/biplavc/dist_AoI_ver5 this is the repo. and the error can be reproduced by running the main_tf.py file by 'python main_tf.py'. The repo also has a yaml file to recreate the conda environment